# Loading a temporary array and looping over it

Tags: sas

I have two datasets with location information - latitude and longitude.

I'm trying to find the closest location from dataset B to the location in dataset A. To do this, I'm trying to use a temporary array but for some reason I keep getting looping error. I've done this many times before but can't see my error today!

The playground dataset is relatively small (647) and the residential data set has about 300K observations.

```
data house_park;

if _n_=1 then i=1 to 647;
set playground (rename=(latitude=lat longitude=long));
array plat(647) _temporary_;
array plong(647) _temporary_;
array park(647) $100 _temporary_;

plat(i)=lat;
plong(i)=long;
park(i)=name;
end;
end;

length nearest_park $100.;
min_dist=999999;
nearest_park="";

do k=1 to 647;
dist=geodist(latitude, longitude, plat(k), plong(k));
if dist<min_dist then min_dist=dist;
nearest_park=park(k);
end;
run;
```

Comment: I had no idea the geodist function existed - I recently had to write a macro to calculate it in 9.1.3 `:(`

Comment: On a side-note.  You should consider using `lbound()` and `hbound()` to setup your loop limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 2 of your code you have:

```
if _n_=1 then i=1 to 647;
```

Did you mean to type this instead?

```
if _n_=1 then do i=1 to 647;
```

Also, you only have 1 set statement - I presume you've deliberately left out the part of your code that reads in rows from the residential data set?